# How can heapq's push operation be O(log n) time if the underlying data structure is a list?

Tags: python, time-complexity, heapq

Doesn't a list require O(n) time to increase its size? How, then, could heap.heappush be O(log n)?

Comment: "Doesn't a list require O(n) to increase its size" - no? Or at least, it's only O(n) worst case. It's O(1) amortized.

Comment: You might be thinking of insertion time, but `heapq.heappush` isn't a list insertion operation.

Comment: I was confused. I thought that lists were arrays.

Comment: @LayGonzález: They maintain arrays under the hood, but they're resizable, and they overallocate (maintaining size and capacity separately; there's usually some space available to append elements without resizing) to make `append`s and `pop`s from the end amortized `O(1)`. Think C++ `vector`, Java `ArrayList`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `list` has *amortized* `O(1)` appends; every once in a long while, it needs to expand the underlying capacity, but usually an `append` just needs to claim already allocated capacity.

So yes, every once in a while, `heapq.heappush` will incur `O(n)` work to reallocate the underlying `list`'s storage, but the vast majority of the time, adding the extra item (done via `append` internally) is `O(1)`, which is followed by a `O(log n)` sift down operation to move it to the correct position in the heap (reestablishing the heap invariant); the sift down operation is implemented with element swaps, which are all `O(1)`, not insertions and deletions (which would be `O(n)` each)